# Using Generics to avoid casting when caching different types

Tags: c#, generics, caching, casting, stackexchange.redis

I am using ASP.NET Core and Redis Cache. I am trying to store different types of different objects in the cache and I want to avoid explicit casting.

This is My wrapper For the Redis Cache

```
public class RedisCacheStorage : Contracts.ICacheStorage
{
    private CachingFramework.Redis.Context _context = null;

    public RedisCacheStorage(string configuration)
    {
        _context = new CachingFramework.Redis.Context(configuration, new CachingFramework.Redis.Serializers.JsonSerializer());
    }
    public void SetItem<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        _context.Cache.SetObject<T>(key, value);
    }
    public T GetItem<T>(string key)
    {
        return _context.Cache.GetObject<T>(key);
    }

    public T GetItem<T>(string key, Func<T> loadCacheFunc)
    {
        return _context.Cache.FetchObject<T>(key, loadCacheFunc);
    }
```

Then I Inject ICacheStorage in CacheManager (which implements ICacheManager). I am trying to isolate  the dependencies and keeping the CacheStorage simple, so when I need to change the cache type I just implement the ICacheStorage. In CacheManager, we are injecting all Services that get some data when special keys are passed.

**CacheManager**:

```
  public class CacheManager : Contracts.ICacheManager
{
    private Contracts.ICacheStorage _cacheStorage;
    private SecurityCore.ServiceContracts.IParametersService _paramService;
    public CacheManager(Contracts.ICacheStorage cacheStorage, SecurityCore.ServiceContracts.IParametersService paramService)
    {
        _cacheStorage = cacheStorage;
        _paramService = paramService;
    }
    public Object GetItem(string key)
    {
        if (key == Constants.CacheKeys.SecuritySystemParams)
            return _cacheStorage.GetItem<Dictionary<string, string>>(key, _paramService.GetSystemParameters);

        //if (key == Constants.CacheKeys.EffectivePermissions)
        //   return  List of Effective Permissions

        return _cacheStorage.GetItem<Object>(key);
    }
```

*`_cacheStorage.GetItem<Dictionary<string, string>>(key, _paramService.GetSystemParameters);`*

Passes a function that uses the Fetch Method of the Redis, if the cache was empty, it calls the service, then store the data in cache and return it back.

My Problem is that I need to avoid casting, because I might be returning different objects, How i can keep using Generics, So I pass the type of the object returned.

As you see below a compilation error, due to cannot convert the type object to Dictionay and this needs explicit casting to be resolved.

Is there better, elegant way to implement the Whole idea?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the error message.
You need to explicitly specify the type parameter.

You can make this much better with type-safe keys:

```
class CacheKey<T> {
    public string Name { get; }
    public string ToString() => Name;
    public CacheKey(string name) { Name = name; }
}

public T GetItem<T>(CacheKey<T> key) { ... }

public CacheKey<Dictionary<string, string>> SecuritySystemParams { get; } = new CacheKey<Dictionary<string, string>>("SecuritySystemParams");
```

This will let `GetItem()` infer `T` from the key, and will prevent you from passing the wrong type.

Comment: `public T GetItem<T>(CacheKey<T> key)
        {
            if (key.Name == SecuritySystemParams.Name)
                return _cacheStorage.GetItem<T>(key.Name, _paramService.GetSystemParameters());

            return _cacheStorage.GetItem<T>(key.Name);
        }`. I guess I misunderstood this,  but we still missing something since it cannot cast the returned object of `_paramService.GetSystemParameters()` to `T`. So, how the implemenation would change internally.